# Convert list of both characters and integers to characters in scala

Tags: scala, char

Let's say I want to convert the following list consisting of both characters and integers:

```
List(1,2,3,'-',' ').map(a => something(a.toChar))
```

for some method something. Now a.toChar will be a character, but not like '1', '2' and '3'. Similarly, tricks for the integers won't work for the characters. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by this `Now a.toChar will be a character, but not like '1', '2' and '3'` ?

Comment: What tricks are you talking about ?

Comment: 1.toChar != '1', 2.toChar != '2', ... One trick I found was a => a + '0'.

Comment: I tried '-'.toString.charAt(0) and 2.toString.charAt(0) and it worked fine, but for a list List(1,2,3,'-',' ').map(a => a.toString.charAt(0))  it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Scala considers this `List(1,2,3,'-',' ')` to be a `List[Int]` with elements like `' '` being just a different way to express the integer value of 32.

If you want to change this `List[Int]` into a `List[Char]`, keeping the current character representations but expressing all single digit integer values as their ASCII character equivalent, you might do something like this.

```
List(1,2,3,'-',' ').map(x => if (x <= 9) (x+48).toChar else x.toChar)
// res0: List[Char] = List(1, 2, 3, -,  )
```

But you could still encounter `Int` values that aren't printable characters.  It's better to avoid these mixed-type collections altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the integer within the range to char by converting it to intermediate string and getting the 0 th index char.

In case of valid byte convert it into char.

In case of any other integer or object have a case in the pattern matching and convert to appropriate result.

```
scala>  List(1,2,3,'-',' ').map {
     |    case a if a >= 0 && a <= 9 => s"$a"(0)
     |    case b if b.isValidByte => b.toByte.toChar
     | }
res19: List[Char] = List(1, 2, 3, -,  )
```